# in iPhone App set focus on textView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview, uitextview

In my iPhone App I have put textField and TextView both
and I have grouped them with scrollview

now the problem is when I call

```
[textField becomeBecomeFirstResponder];
```

it sets focus  on textField in scrollView and makes content Area visible in scrollView accordingly

But When I do same thing with UItextView:

```
[textView becomeBecomeFirstResponder];
```

it does not make TextView visible in scroll view i.e it does not focus on textView (cursor sets on text view but content area of scrollview dose not appear with out manual scrolling)

What shoud I do to set focus on textView and set content area accordingly in in scrollview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your trouble here is that UITextView is a UIScrollView, while UITextField is a UIControl.

It is quite likely, though I have not tested this in code at the moment, that the best way to handle this is to watch for `textView.isFirstResponder` and when true, call `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textView.frame animated:YES]` on your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure u have set textView's delegate.

Comment: @Shyam Thanks but I have already set the delegates for textView